# Como puedo enviar notificaciones push desde python?

Tags: python, firebase, push-notification, push

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que se comunique con Firebase y este envíe notificaciones push a un dispositivo unico en Android, ya he podido realizar el envío de las notificaciones desde Firebase pero no desde un programa en Python.

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>")

proxy_dict = {
          "http"  : "http://127.0.0.1",
          "https" : "http://127.0.0.1",
        }
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>", proxy_dict=proxy_dict)

registration_id = "<device registration_id>"
message_title = "Prueba"
message_body = "Mensaje de prueba"
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)

print result
```

estoy usando el api key que otorta Firebase y el token id o registration id de la app la cual va a recibir la notificacion.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses PyFCM https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM es sencillo de utilizar. ya lo he usado para enviar notificaciones push para firebase desde python